# How to optimize audio in game?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a problem with audio when making game in browser. For example when i hit shot with sound effect a lot of time there is error:

blocked attempt to create a webmediaplayer as there are too many webmediaplayers already in existence.

I don;t know, these sound elements are saving in any place and i need to delete it or what? I delete just all instance of class when shot is behind the screen.

I make audio just in constructor:
new Audio("./audio/LaserShot.wav")

and play() in proper function

Comment: Maybe just cache a set of audio objects. And when you need reuse one, just set the `src` property on it?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480528/blocked-attempt-to-create-a-webmediaplayer-as-there-are-too-many-webmediaplayers)