# Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, html5-audio

We are working on a Digital Audio Workstation kind of thing in the browser. We need to work with multiple audio files in a tab. We use `new Audio(audioUrl)` to be able to play the audio in our own audio mixer. It has been working for us up to now.

With the latest version of Chrome (92), we have the problem where the above code snippet causes the following error:

```
[Intervention] Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. See crbug.com/1144736#c27
```

I cannot access the bug link provided, it says permission denied. And is there a suggested workaround to handle this?

**UPDATE:**
I moved away from using `HTMLAudioElement` to `AudioBufferSourceNode`. Seems like the only straightforward solution as Chrome team is discussing to limit them anyway. **Note:** We may need more than 1000 audio clips to be played back. This is in reference to the chromium discussion thread where they are going to increase the number of `webmediaplayers` to 1000 on the next release for August 5 2021.

Comment: Related source code changes https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2816118

Comment: I solved this problem by setting in the HTML the attribute "preload" for lazy loading: preload="none" (full example: <audio src="…" preload="none"></audio>). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome 92 has introduced a limit on number of audio and video tags that can be allocated in a particular tab.
75 for desktop browsers and 40 for mobile browsers.

For now the only solution is to limit the number of audio and video tags created in the page. Try reusing the already allocated audio / video elements.

The number can only be increased by passing the following flag when starting up chrome, for example `--max-web-media-player-count=5000`
(Of course we cannot expect the end user to do this)

Related Source code here:
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2816118

Edit:

Before deallocating the audio/video elements setting the following seems to force clean up of the element.

```
mediaElement.remove();
mediaElement.srcObject = null;
```

Comment: It looks like these limits may be raised to [200 for desktop and 100 for mobile](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/9e03c50a4b268bbca6f2cba903131b88072420d7).

Comment: Looks like the entire change will be reverted.

Comment: They will be raising the limit to 1,000 in the August 3, 2021 update. The discussion can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232649).

Comment: chrome ignores this flag.anyone ever figured it out?

Comment: I don't know if setting `srcObject` to `null` works. I know `mediaElement.src = '';` works for me. You can determine for sure using chrome://media-internals. See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232649#c18 and https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/media-dev/c/wEUYR7BvdZI/m/R-8X1EdiBAAJ?pli=1

Answer (score 6):

```
const MaxWebMediaPlayerCount = 75;

class VideoProducer {
  static #documentForVideo

  static createVideo() {
    if (!this.#documentForVideo || this.#documentForVideo.videoCount === MaxWebMediaPlayerCount) {
      const iframeForVideo = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
      iframeForVideo.style.display = 'none';
      iframeForVideo.contentDocument.videoCount = 0;
      this.#documentForVideo = iframeForVideo.contentDocument;
    }
    this.#documentForVideo.videoCount++;
    const video = this.#documentForVideo.createElement('video');
    return video;
  }

  foo() {
    const video = VideoProducer.createVideo();
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Wait. So you can get around this by creating videos inside an iframe, and making that your new video document root? I don't know how to feel...

Answer (score 3):

Yeah me too it broke my game,
This is what I found as a workaround, hope this helps in the mean time:

```
function playSound(  ) {
    var jump_sound = new Audio("./jump.mp3");
    jump_sound.play();

    jump_sound.onended = function(){
        this.currentSrc = null;
        this.src = "";
        this.srcObject = null;
        this.remove();
    };
}
```

Note: it still blocks if there's too many concurrent sound but with this code in place the blocking is temporary.

Comment: At least the `removeAttribute('src')` part doesn't seem to actually destroy the media player. You can prove this with chrome://media-internals. Instead, do `this.src = '';`. I think it's weird that you must assign empty string, but it works. See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1232649#c18 and https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/media-dev/c/wEUYR7BvdZI/m/R-8X1EdiBAAJ?pli=1

Comment: I edited this answer to use `src = ''` instead of `removeAttribute('src')`

Comment: Note: `src = ''` worked for me in my situation. Use chrome://media-internals to verify whatever solution you use actually destroys the audio player in your situation.

Comment: `currentSrc` is a getter on chrome, attempting to set it will throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome version 92.0.4515.131 seems to resolve the issue

Comment: If we are using more than 1000 elements, it's still a problem. The commit on chromium source has hard-coded 1000 elements. 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/92.0.4515.107..92.0.4515.131?pretty=fuller&n=10000
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f7489718ee87fbef92c59d35d9437cf55466fa2c%5E%21/#F0