# Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. How do I remove an existing WebMediaPlayer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I have a web application that takes photos from a camera and saves them. With the update to Chrome 92, after 75 photos I get the following:

[Intervention] Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. See [crbug.com/1144736#c27](https://crbug.com/1144736#c27)

(Addition: I use an HTMLMediaElement and MediaStream for a camera preview, this preview stops working after 75 ajax reloads. I can continue to take photos normally.)

I want to know how to dispose of the WebMediaPlayer after a photo has been taken, so that the camera reloads properly when the page comes back. For testing, I've set `--max-web-media-player-count=1`, following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503181/10392988

I have tried to unload the HTMLMediaElement that loads the WebMediaPlayer. I've tried setting the src attributes and the element itself to blank and null. I've tried to load() the camera after the src changes. Nothing I've tried seems to get rid of the WebMediaPlayer instance. I can remove the HTMLMediaElement, but the WebMediaPlayer seems to stick around.

Comment: Did you clear the `srcObject` of your element? Also, your whole process is a bit unclear, IIUC you are taking photos from a MediaStream? Then the best (when available) is to use the [ImageCapture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture).

Comment: @Kaiido I am using the MediaStream for the camera preview. I can take photos past the 75 limit, but the preview does not load after the limit is reached. I have tried preview.removeAttribute('srcObject'), delete preview.srcObject, preview.srcObject = null, and preview.srcObject = ''. I also tried calling preview.load() after these commands, but the WebMediaPlayer instance does not appear to be removed. The WebMediaPlayers seem to be tied to the preview HTMLMediaElement and not the MediaStream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480528/blocked-attempt-to-create-a-webmediaplayer-as-there-are-too-many-webmediaplayers)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Kaiido, clearing the srcObject did remove the WebMediaPlayer instance. I set up a specific test page to experiment with this, and setting HTMLMediaElement.srcObject = null before replacing the HTMLMediaElement did eliminate the Intervention error. The error in my live code must be related to something else.